# common idf scoring across all multimatch query fields with elasticsearch

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

With the following **document set**:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test/books/1" -d '{
  "title": "Bacon Dishes",
  "tags": ["bacon", "cooking"]
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test/books/2" -d '{
  "title": "Beyond Bacon",
  "tags" : ["cooking"]
}'
```

And the following **query**:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test/books/_search?pretty=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch" -d ' {
  "explain" : true,
  "query" : {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "bacon beyond",
      "fields" : ["title^2","tags^1"]
    }
  }
}'
```

The explain plan shows that the score for title is calculated using `idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=2)` while the score for tags (if present) is calculated using `idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=2)`.

This becomes a problem (at least for us) when there are 100 books where 50 have "bacon" in the title and only 1 has "bacon" in the tags but does not have "bacon" in the title. Using the query above, the document with "bacon" in the tags will be scored higher, despite title being boosted.

I would like for the score calculations for both the tag and title fields in the first example to be:

```
 idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=2)
```

That is, I would like the score calculation to use the docFreq of a term across all fields in the multimatch query. Is this possible?

Comment: I would just increase the boost that you give to the title, enough to make it more important than tags. I don't think you want to implement your own custom similarity and plug it in elasticsearch :)

Comment: You're right, I definitely wouldn't want to do such a thing! Would you happen to know if any of the options/settings here enable the behavior I'm looking for? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html

Comment: No, you just have to make the title weight higher, that's it. higher enough that it makes it important as you want it to be compared to tags. Of course this is fine-tuning, which needs to happen with a real index, real data, real queries...

Comment: Thanks. Please convert your comment to an answer. I'll accept it if no other answers come in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just increase the boost that you give to the title, enough to make it more important than the tags field.

I don't think you want to implement your own custom similarity and plug it in elasticsearch.

Just keep in mind that adding proper weights to fields and playing around with boosting is fine-tuning, which needs to happen with a real index, real data, real queries.